# Calculating the total size of all files from a particular date to till date using find command

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a folder with multiple subfolders. Need to calculate the total size of all files from a particular date to till date using find command. I tried with below commands. Not working.

```
find . -type -f -newerat 2020-01-05 ! -newerat 2020-02-10
```

Regards

Comment: do you want to calculate the total file-size, or the total diskspace? (two different things)

Answer (score 3):

The command you wrote is almost everything we need.

We start by listing all the files that we want to count the size of.

```
$ find . -type f -newerat 2020-02-01 ! -newerat 2020-02-11

./c/1
./a/1
./a/3
./a/2
./b/1
./b/2
```

This gives us a list of all the files we want to consider. What we need to do now is get the size of each file. As @XrXca said in the comments, we can use the find's `printf` option to get each file's size in bytes.

```sh
$ find . -type f -newerat 2020-02-01 ! -newerat 2020-02-11 -printf="%s\\n" 
4
4
4
4
4
4
```

This gives us a nice list of the files size.

Now we just need to sum them up. To do so, we can use a little bit of awk:

```sh
$ find . -type f -newerat 2020-02-01 ! -newerat 2020-02-11 -printf="%s\\n" | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'

24
```

and that's the cumulative size of the filtered files, in bytes.

Comment: avoid writing the filename, just the size should be enough. You might have filenames with newlines which mess things up.

Comment: You're right, I was printing the filenames only for clarity

Comment: The xargs shouldn't be needed, find has a -printf option that will print the file size in bytes.so adding `-printf "%s\n"` to the find command and piping that to the awk should do it.

Comment: @XrXca is right, I did not know about the `find` option

Comment: @user1726453 If this reply answers your question you should accept it

Comment: Should be space instead of `=` between `-printf "%s\\n"` otherwise it will fails with `find: unknown predicate -printf=%s\n'`

Answer (score 0):

The below command gives the file type, name of file/directory, last modified time and size

```
find . -exec stat -c "%F,%n,%y,%s" '{}' +|column -t -s,
```