# How can I determine disk usage of folders of a particular date in bash?

Tags: date, directory, disk

There is many of thousands of folders and hundreds per day.
How can I find out in bash how much disk space folders of a particular date use ?

Answer (score 0):

`perl -MPOSIX -e 'for ( grep {-d} glob ( "*" ) ) { print join "\t", strftime("%Y-%m-%d",gmtime((stat)[9])),` du -sm $_ `}' | grep "<date>" | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s}'`

The summing up is done by the awk-command.

I have combined answers of following posts:

1. List size of folders and their changed date
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250898/list-size-of-folders-and-their-changed-date
   → `perl -MPOSIX -e 'for ( grep {-d} glob ( "*" ) ) { print join "\t", strftime("%Y-%m-%d",gmtime((stat)[9]))),` du -sh $_ `}'`
2. Calculating the total size of all files from a particular date to till date using find command
   [Calculating the total size of all files from a particular date to till date using find command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147882/calculating-the-total-size-of-all-files-from-a-particular-date-to-till-date-usin)
   → does not work in my environment, but combining 1) and 2) I could find the solution that work in my environment.